# Tableau FIXED LOD vs COUNTD

Tags: tableau-desktop, level-of-detail

I am working with a dataset containing **22,232,726** entries collected between 2008 and 2021. Because original entries can not be deleted from the database, a new entry must be created with the same ID to update an observation.
I want to remove all repeated IDs leaving only the latest entry per ID for my analysis.
I used the following Level of Detail function in Tableau to achieve this:
`{FIXED [ID]: MAX([Date])} = [Date]`
The function returns a total of **17,980,416** entries. However, when I run a distinct count `COUNTD([ID])` before and after applying the LOD filter, I get **17,899,956** distinct IDs. Why is my LOD function returning an extra **80,460** repeated IDs to the result?
FYI, there are no Nulls in the ID nor the Date columns. So there can be repeated dates for the same ID, but I expected Tableau to keep only one of them in the results. How can I remove these extra repeated entries or fix this counting problem?

Comment: For each ID, this approach keeps ALL records that have the MAX date for that ID. So if there are multiple records with the same ID that happen to fall on the last day for that ID, those will all be included. Might be a bit less of an issue if your Date field has the date-time datatype instead of just date.

Comment: Do you have a tie-breaker rule in mind? or do you want to just randomly select one of the late arrivals? This might be a good use for Tableau Prep to slim your data down prior to analysis for speed, leaving the original untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a solution to the problem by using a Row_ID field as the criterium for selecting one of the records with an identical ID and Date. I used 2 LOD calcs as filters.

The first filter kept all unique IDs with the latest Date, including some repeated IDs with the same latest date.

1:`{FIXED [ID]: MAX([Date])} = [Date]`

The second filter took the repeated records with identical ID and Date and kept only the one with the last Row_ID.

2:`{FIXED [ID],[Date]: MAX([Row_ID])}=[Row_ID]`

The original dataset doesn't have a Row_ID variable, so I had to create it by using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) in Python by adding `index` and `index_label` parameters:

```
df.to_csv("my-file-name.csv", index=True, index_label='Row_ID')
```